# How to refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 16 to the 15 allowed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sonarqube

when I add this check:
card.targetUrl !== "/test"

I get this error and I cannot commit, how do I reduce this complexity?

```
 const link = useMemo(() => {
    if (!card?.targetUrl || card.targetUrl === "/test") {
      return "/account";
    } else {
      return card.targetUrl;
    }
  }, [card]);
```

this error is not present when the code looks like this:

```
const link = useMemo(() => {
    if (card?.targetUrl) {
      return card.targetUrl;
    } else {
      return "/account";
    }
  }, [card]);
```

Comment: `card?.targetUrl !== "/test"`? You don't need the extra condition, because undefined is already not equal to that string. If you didn't have test-specific logic in your implementation, you could just `return card?.targetUrl ?? "/account/wallet"`

Comment: I need to check specifically for the "/test" url @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `useMemo`. It takes more CPU time than calculations inside of it.

```
const link = !card || card.targetUrl === "/test" ? "/account" : card.targetUrl
```

With `useMemo`, each render you have to create a function, get previously stored dependencies, loop through it, and even if there were no changes you already spent ten times more CPU time that simple string compare.
And if card was changed, then... uhh. execute the function, store return value somewhere, replace dependencies.. ohh.. and store hook into hook execution chain... I believe even more overhead is here.

Comment: This does reduce the CPU time indeed, but how and why does it decrease the cognitive complexity measure?

Comment: Good catch :) but probably we should look to other parts of the function, that are definitely more scary.

Answer (score 1):

Cognitive complexity is increased when there are breaks in the linear flow of control. `if`, `else` blocks and early returns may increase it. You can remove one inner block and the early returns by initialising a variable with the default value, like this:

```
const link = useMemo(() => {
    let url = card?.targetUrl;
    if (!url || url === "/test") {
       url = "/account";
    }
    return url;
  }, [card]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Cognitive Complexity can be [defined](https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/cognitive-complexity) as "*a measure of how difficult a unit of code is to intuitively understand*".

To me, the intent of your code as it is now is not very obvious, since I need to mentally compute the null check, the negation, the `or` and the equality on the right side. Doesn't seem like much when we're writing it, but others (and even you later) might find it difficult to read, hence the high cognitive complexity score.

I have some suggestions for you in order to make it simpler to understand:

1. Have each condition in a separate `if` clause:

   ```js
   const link = useMemo(() => {
     if (card?.targetUrl == null) {
       return "/account";
     }
     if (card.targetUrl === "/test") {
       return "/account";
     }
     return card.targetUrl;
   }, [card]);
   ```

   Some people might be hesitant to repeat the same return value (remember DRY?), but making your code easier to read and easier to change makes it worthwhile. For instance, maybe you'll want to remove the `card.targetUrl === "/test"` condition at a later time, in the sample code above it would be easy because they're separate.
2. Don't use the `else` keyword.

   Since your code is doing early returns, the `else` clause is not needed. This advice comes from [Object Calisthenics](https://medium.com/@davidsen/clean-code-object-calisthenics-f6f4dec07c8b), check it out.
3. If you don't want to repeat returns, there's another way to make the code more readable by extracting the condition into a new function and giving it a descriptive name (pardon my rusty Javascript):

   ```js
   const link = useMemo(() => {
     if (shouldUseDefaultUrl(card)) {
       return "/account";
     }
     return card.targetUrl;
   }, [card]);

   function shouldUseDefaultUrl(card) {
     if (card?.targetUrl == null) {
       return true;
     }
     if (card.targetUrl === "/test") {
       return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
   ```